# how to make a scroll view to scroll over another layout with the layout behind staying intact but behind scroll content

Tags: android, android-layout

how to make a scroll view to scroll over another layout with the layout behind staying intact but behind scroll content
   my requirement is the header of an application will stay fixed while the layout below it will scroll over if the content in it is large enough to scroll,please provide me or suggest any solution to this problem

Comment: It is not sufficient to put your scrollview "over" your header with the option paddingTop??Like this when your scrollView has to scroll it will go over your previous layout.

Comment: i did try padding top, header layout stays on top,but i want the scroller to move over the header layout

Comment: I really don't understand what your problem is, and how are we supposed to help you if you don't show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="269dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- any no. of views here -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to onCreate():

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    Layout.setY(Layout.getY() + scrollView.getScrollY() - Layout.getY());


                }
            });
```

Every time the view is scrolls, the layout will move the opposite value. Which  looks like it's not moving at all. Make sure all your views are inside the ScrollView.